# Checking the number of downloads for a file

Tags: php, apache2

I have a `.exe` file located in a directory on my server running on Apache 2. Is there any way to check the number of downloads for a specific file and display it on my webpage (CMS written in PHP)? What do I need to do in order to achieve that? I tried to add a record to my MySQL database on every click of a link on my webpage (it's working), but I need a count **all** of the downloads, not only by my link (that means including a count of the direct downloads by writing for example `http://example.com/file.exe`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try an [Apache rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) , for instance, you could rewrite every request to any .exe file to be redirected to a php as a parameter. Then you can use the mechanism you designed (MySQL records in a database).